# VS2017 - Framework 4.6.2 is not shown as an option in a class library project in c#, but it is in a vb windows forms one

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

It's the same visual studio 2017 instalation. I've already downloaded and installed the net framework 4.6.2 developer pack from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks)

[image: windows forms project I've created]

[image: class library project I've downloaded and want to switch framework]

Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you created the C# library, I assume you selected a .Net Standard Library instead of a Windows Classic Desktop library. You can modify the `csproj` file by hand and change the target framework to .Net 4.6.2 like so:

```
<TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
```

Once you do that, the UI should updated in the Project Properties screen.

Comment: Thank you very much! The class library project was downloaded from the web, is not mine, and it's OK to be a class library project. I don't why I couldn't point it to a 4.6.2 class library project from the project options (but it can be done the way you suggest)? Thanks again!